# Windows 8: Default start menu to open on second display

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

I have two monitors and I want to keep it soley on my second monitor. I can do this manually by opening the start menu from the secondary monitor and by default next time I open the start menu it will open on the second monitor.

Is there an option where I can force it to stay on the secondary display. If I restart or accidently open start from the primary monitor it changes the default start menu display monitor to my primary monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your monitors around so that the secondary monitor is to the left of the primary.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use WIN + PAGE UP or WIN + PAGE DOWN to move the Start Screen, or Modern Apps for that matter, around.  You haven't needed to physically move monitors since the early days of Windows XP.